# React useSelector and getState returning different values in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've been following the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) to create and dispatch asynchronous thunks (created with `createAsyncThunk`) to load some user state.

I have two components, say `A` and `B`, and they both need access to the same `userState` information. I'm not sure which will complete rendering first, so I've added the ability to dispatch the information they need to both:

```
// both in component A and B ...
const status = useSelector(selectUserStateStatus);

useEffect(()=>{
   if (status === "idle") {
       dispatch(fetchUserState());
   }
}, [status] );

//...
```

However, both are consistently dispatching `fetchUserState()` so I wind up with unnecessary duplicate requests.

I would think that (in the scenario that the useEffect triggers in `A` first):

1. `A` completes render, `useEffect` is called when `status==="idle"`
2. `fetchUserState` is dispatched, setting `status = "loading"`
3. A re-render of `B` is triggered, with `status === "loading"`
4. `B` doesn't send a new request

However, this is not what happens. `A` and `B` both dispatch `fetchUserState`, resulting in duplicate dispatches.

If I use `store.getState()` however, expected behavior results with only a single dispatch. IE:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if (store.getState().status === "idle") {
       dispatch(fetchUserState());
   }
}, [store.getState().status] );
```

This feels like an anti-pattern though. I'm confused by this behavior, any suggestions on how to remedy this or archetype it more effectively?

Comment: How components A and B are related. Is Component A is parent of B of child of B??

Comment: A is an indirect parent of B (ie B->C-> ... ->A)

Answer (score 0):

1. use [lodash/throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) on the API layer for cancelling first request
2. use common handler for all nesting components

```
function UserStateProvider() {
  const isInitRef = useRef(false)
  const status = useSelector(selectUserStateStatus);

  const fetchUser = () => {
    if (isInitRef.current === false) {
      dispatch(fetchUserState())
      isInitRef.current = true
    }
  }

  return <ContextProvider value={{
    status: status, // if you need status 
    fetchUser: fetchUser,
  }}>
    {children}
  </ContextProvider>
}

const A = () => {
  const {fetchUser} = useUserStateContext()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser()
  }, [])
}

<UserStateProvider>
  <A />
  <B />
  <A />
</UserStateProvider>

 // sugar, if all what you want it is trigger loading  user
const useLoadUser = () => {
  const {fetchUser} = useUserStateContext()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser()
  }, [])
}

const A = () => {
  useLoadUser()
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, and I'll probably go with a solution like it for the time being. However it does seem to negate the use of Redux at all. If I'm going to keep user state in a provider, I might as well drop using Redux and just perform the async logic and loading in the provider itself.

I also still don't understand the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: The provider just restricts multiple dispatch. All your data stores in the store and can be accessed from any place of application. Probably if you will change provider name to someone else it close confusing question